# C# Windows Forms application Process.Start() gives an "Access is denied" error

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, desktop-application, desktop

I work on a C# Windows Forms application ([WinForms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)) and used the following code:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("x");
```

Where `x` is the path to the folder that should be open (a local folder not in *C:\*).

The problem is that when running the program it gives me an "Access is denied" error.

I searched on Google, but I did not find how to solve this problem.

Note: This code works on console applications and Windows Forms (.NET framework).

Comment: A folder is not a process (executable).  You can't use Process.Start to "start" a folder.

Comment: @TimothyG. not true. If you pass a folder then file explorer starts showing the folder

Comment: @Steve Say what??? Thats news to me.  Interesting...  Isn't there an Open folder dialog of some sort though in winforms? It's been a long time since I did winforms coding.

Comment: Yes, there is an OpenFileDialog and a FolderBrowser control that you can use for the respective tasks. (Getting a file name or a folder name in code). Passing a folder path to Process.Start will open that folder using the File explorer and that's all. No interaction with your own code follows.

Comment: So, @Steve Do you know why it gives me an error ?

Comment: As explained in the answer below is a permission problem. You don't have permission to access that folder. By the way, there are many folders that are not accessible if you are not an adminstrator or run VS as administrator. What is exactly the folder that gives you the error?

Comment: Under .Net core Process.Start() will *not* launch a folder path in explorer - it will throw *Access is denied*.

Comment: @AlexK. true, probably a change to have better compatibility with different OS

Comment: .NETCore requires using ProcessStartInfo so you can set its UseShellExecute property to true.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a standard permissions issue. The account running the application does not have the correct permissions to access the folder. If you are debugging from Visual Studio, then try running Visual Studio as an administrator. If you are running an installation of the application then run the application itself as an administrator.

It looks like simply calling `Process.Start` with the folder path will not work in .NET Core. In .NET Core you need to specify the application as well as the folder path:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", "[FolderPath]");
```

Comment: I Tried that already, but it seems .net core does not support that :(

Comment: Not sure what you mean by .net core does not support that, it's not a .net core feature it's a windows feature. What exactly did you try?

Comment: I meant like what someone said above
"Under .Net core Process.Start() will not launch a folder path in explorer - it will throw Access is denied. – 
Alex K.
1 hour ago"

Comment: Understood, updated my answer